# apt-get install openssh-server doesn't work due to unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm new to Ubuntu environment, its been bothering me since a while.

have tried almost everything suggested in the forums but no luck.
I don't know if I'm missing something.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64bit

```
~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: libck-connector0 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not installable
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -f install` now try your install again.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Read it, tried them still no luck

Comment: Did you look to see what packages you have held? `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` what is the output

Comment: Yes got nothing

Comment: What if you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: ran the update command and the `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` , got the same error

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: got it !!, i downloaded the `libck-connector0` from ubuntu package repsitory , installed it using `sudo dpkg -i libck-connector0_0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` and then tried it again. Thanks for your help , really appreciate it.

Comment: Good job! You can add an answer to your own question and accept it if you wish, if you do leave me a comment and I will up vote it.

Answer (score 3):

got it !!, I downloaded the `libck-connector0` from Ubuntu package repository , installed it using `sudo dpkg -i libck-connector0_0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` and then tried it again. It worked this time.

and check this link [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), this guy covered all possible scenarios for such errors.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the output of `apt-cache policy libck-connector0`? That might reveal the original cause of the problem. Because your way is not the cleanest solution, I think...

Comment: I agree but had to get it working,                                                              this is what I got `~$ sudo apt-cache policy libck-connector0 
[sudo] password for skillshot: 
libck-connector0:
  Installed: 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: This is strange. Does the output change after running `sudo apt-get update`? There should appear a line starting with "500". If not, please show me the output of `grep "^deb .*main" /etc/apt/sources.list`, there could be a misconfiguration which will cause problems on every future package installation if it's what I think.

Comment: The output didn't change for `apt-cache policy libck-connector0` and for the second command this is the output `~$ grep "^deb .*main" /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main`

Comment: Very strange, I have no idea... :-/

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link. Your problem is solved only partially.

Comment: And also the full output of `apt-cache policy libck-connector0`. (No need for a `sudo` here.)

Comment: here's my sources.list =>http://paste.ubuntu.com/14567877/ and output for `apt-cache policy libck-connector0`   => `~$ apt-cache policy libck-connector0
libck-connector0:
  Installed: 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`